# /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID

Tags: snmp, snmpd, net-snmp

using ubuntu with net-snmp
snmp work but in sys.log i see a lot of errors about snmpd.conf

**snmpd.conf**:

```
rwcommunity community 10.0.0.1
rwcommunity community 10.0.0.2
agentAddress  udp:10.0.0.1:161

view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1


                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly

rouser   authOnlyUser

sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>

sysServices    72

proc  mountd                          
proc  ntalkd    4                        
proc  sendmail 10 1

disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

load   12 10 5

trapsink     localhost public

iquerySecName   internalUser       
rouser          internalUser

defaultMonitors          yes

linkUpDownNotifications  yes

master          agentx
```

**errors**:

```
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: prNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: prNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: prErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: prErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: prErrorFlag
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: memErrorName
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: memErrorName
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: memSwapErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: memSwapErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: memSwapError
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: extNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: extNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: extOutput
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: extOutput
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: extResult
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: dskPath
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: dskPath
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: dskErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: dskErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: dskErrorFlag
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: laNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: laNames
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: laErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: laErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: laErrorFlag
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: fileName
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: fileName
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: fileErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: fileErrorMsg
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: fileErrorFlag
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: payload OID: snmperrErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Unknown payload OID: snmperrErrMessage
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: Unknown payload OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: trigger OID: snmperrErrorFlag
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 5: Error: unknown monitor OID
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: Turning on AgentX master support.
Sep 12 16:35:00 test snmpd[5485]: net-snmp: 33 error(s) in config file(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 12.04 (which was causing the same messages for me) the full steps to get SNMP working appear to be as follows :

1. Install snmpd : `apt-get install snmpd`
2. Ensure the multiverse repository is enabled :

   ```
   apt-get install python-software-properties
   add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse'
   apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the snmp-mibs-downloader : `apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader`
4. Edit `/etc/default/snmpd/` and set `MIBS=UCD-SNMP-MIB` (this is the key fix)
5. Restart snmpd : `/etc/init.d/snmpd restart`

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 15.10 too. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Debian documentation](http://wiki.debian.org/SNMP), try commenting out the following line in `/etc/default/snmpd`:

```
export MIBS=/usr/share/snmp/mibs
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12087748&postcount=2